# Validate email in a contact form using jQuery/javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, forms, if-statement

I'm trying to validate a contact form using jQuery. The name field validates correctly using this function, but no matter what I do I get the error message in the email input whenever I try to send, even with a valid email. At this point I'm truly lost and would really appreciate the help. I'm pretty sure the problem is in the regex in the email if statement `(!/^S+@S+.S+$/.test(email.val()))`, but I just can't figure it out. Here is the function I am using

```
$(function(){

    var required = ["name", "email", "message"];
    emptyerror = "Please fill out this field";
    emailerror = "Please enter a valid e-mail";
    email = $("#email");
    errornotice = $("#error");

    $("#contactForm").submit(function() {
      for (var i = 0; i < required.length; i++) {

        var inputField = $('#'+required[i]);

        if ((inputField.val() == "") || (inputField.val() == emptyerror)) {
          inputField.addClass("needsfilled");
          inputField.val(emptyerror);
          errornotice.fadeIn(750);
        }
        else {
          inputField.removeClass("needsfilled");
        }
        if (!/^S+@S+.S+$/.test(email.val())) {
            email.addClass("needsfilled");
            email.val(emailerror);
        }
        if ($(":input").hasClass("needsfilled")) {
          return false;
        }
        else {
          errornotice.hide();
          return true;
        }
      }
    });

    $(":input").focus(function() {
      if ($(this).hasClass("needsfilled")) {
        $(this).val("");
        $(this).removeClass("needsfilled");
      }
    })
});
```

On a side note, I know that there are way better ways to validate *not* using jQuery/js. But this is for a school project that requires it to be done with javascript, even if it has to be overly simplified.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this method or regex only in your code:

```
function isValidEmail(pEmail) {
    var filter = /^([\w-]+(?:\.[\w-]+)*)@((?:[\w-]+\.)*\w[\w-]{0,66})\.([a-z]{2,6}(?:\.[a-z]{2})?)$/i;

    if (!filter.test(pEmail)) {
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The email validation you are using is not enough. I'd recommend to find out better RegExps for this purpose.

Here's the better RegExp for you:

```
/^((([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+(\.([a-z]|\d|[!#\$%&'\*\+\-\/=\?\^_`{\|}~]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])+)*)|((\x22)((((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(([\x01-\x08\x0b\x0c\x0e-\x1f\x7f]|\x21|[\x23-\x5b]|[\x5d-\x7e]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(\\([\x01-\x09\x0b\x0c\x0d-\x7f]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF]))))*(((\x20|\x09)*(\x0d\x0a))?(\x20|\x09)+)?(\x22)))@((([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|\d|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))\.)+(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])|(([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])([a-z]|\d|-|\.|_|~|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])*([a-z]|[\u00A0-\uD7FF\uF900-\uFDCF\uFDF0-\uFFEF])))$/i
```

Find out information on [regexp **unicode categories**](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#category) being used here, if you need details.

Comment: I can see arabic characters (FDF0).. What other "magic" you regexped ? :)

Comment: @WBAR, not sure I understand you question fully.. please, find out the link, I just added, on **unicode categories**, if you need more understanding.